# Cannot convert value "Int32" to type "System.Int32"

Tags: powershell, type-conversion, int

I am getting some file sizes from some folders, and the value is in bytes. I want to convert them to mB by dividing with 1024, but even though they are both int32, it is not working

I tried a lot of casting, but nothing is sticking

traverse folder returns an int

```
$subsize = (traverseFolder $folderName)
$i = 1024
$bytesToMb = [int]$subsizeType / $i
$fileContent = "$folderName : " + "$bytesToMb 
Add-Content "C:\Users\SolutionTeam\Documents\DBIGroupFolderSizes.txt" $fileContent
```

Error I get:

```
Cannot convert value "Int32" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."
At C:\Users\SolutionTeam\Documents\coding\powershell\getfoldersize\GetSize.ps1:103 char:9
+         $bytesToMb = [int]$subsizeType / [int]$i
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastFromStringToInteger
```

I also did .GetType() on both $i and $subsize:

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Int32                                    System.ValueType
True     True     Int32                                    System.ValueType
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Where is the `$subsizeType` variable coming from?

Comment: Bytes / 1024 --> Kb. Bytes / (1024 * 1024) --> Mb or in PowerShell `$bytesToMb = $subsize / 1Mb`. Also, I would suggest using `[Int64]` for the total size in bytes. Plus, you have a rogue quote `"` in the declaration of `$fileContent`

Comment: Why are you dividing `$subsizeType` by 1024 when it should be `$subsize / 1024`? The error reads as if `$subsizeType` is a string with a value `Int32`.

Comment: The 4th line is not terminated with a quote.

Comment: So I am obviously very embarrassed. Having worked with this for a couple of hours, I got code blind and didnt see that I was using $subsizeType and not $subsize. Sorry guys, but thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$folderName = "c:\Temp"
$fileContent = "$foldername : {0} MB" -f ((Get-ChildItem $folderName -Recurse | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum -ErrorAction Stop).Sum / 1MB)
Add-Content "C:\Users\SolutionTeam\Documents\DBIGroupFolderSizes.txt" $fileContent
```